# No Activity found to handle MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am using this quite simple piece of code to capture an image on an Android device.

```
File tmpFile = ...;
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(tmpFile));
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

This works fine for thousands of users except for one running this on a Kindle device without camera. Today I got a crash report from a device with camera:

```
ANDROID_VERSION=4.2.1
BRAND=Hisense
PHONE_MODEL=M470BSA
STACK_TRACE=android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE (has extras) }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
...
```

I have put some exception handling around the code to catch the exception and show an error, but I have no idea why this piece of code is failing on this device. The user confirmed that the camera is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no requirement that a device have an activity that supports `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, even if the device has an actual camera.

Second, particularly on Android 4.3+ tablets, the person using the device may not have access to an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity, even if one is installed, as the person may be running in a restricted profile.

Comment: In this case, the device is 4.2.1, so no restricted profiles.Yes, could be that there is no Activity to support this, but it still appears very unlikely to me as there is a working camera app on the system. Any way to find this out before starting the Intent? E.g., in order to disable the capture option in my app?

Comment: @farindk: "Yes, could be that there is no Activity to support this, but it still appears very unlikely to me as there is a working camera app on the system" -- Hisense engineers could have written their own camera app and neglected to add support for this. "Any way to find this out before starting the Intent?" -- use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`. If the `List` comes back empty, there is no match, and you'll get an `ActivityNotFoundException` if you try calling `startActivity()`/`startActivityForResult()` on that same `Intent`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there any solution to sort out this ?