# Android No Activity found - STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following exception in my android app.

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA (has extras) }
```

I know that my device, an MC70, has a camera.

```
bool hasFeature = packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA);
int numCameras = android.hardware.Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
```

Both hasFeature is true and numCameras > 0

The device has an SD card installed:

```
Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml file I have:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

This list comes back empty, probably a bad sign:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

This code must run on the MC70, which is limited to KitKat 4 API 19.

But when I call:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
```

I get the exception:

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE (has extras) }
```

I have tried:

- MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
- MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE
- MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA
- MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA_SECURE

All throw the exception.  Why?

Comment: are u using `startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, your_id);` ?

Comment: Yes.  That is the actual line that throws the exception.  I have edited the question above.

Comment: Try running app on different phone, and I couldn't found any proper answer. Even DevGuru said : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902086/no-activity-found-to-handle-mediastore-action-image-capture-intent

Comment: Must run on MC70, dedicated barcode scanner, for work.  Device is limited to KitKat 4 Api 19.  Already read the SO link, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why?

Because the device manufacturer did not install a camera app that supports any of those `Intent` structures. If the device does not legitimately ship with the Play Store on it, there is no requirement that the manufacturer have to meet any particular compatibility requirements.

Assuming that you do not need a camera app with any particular features, install an open source one, like [Open Camera](http://opencamera.sourceforge.net/), so your device has an app that responds to `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, etc.

Comment: We just looked to your old answer but it was no clear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902086/no-activity-found-to-handle-mediastore-action-image-capture-intent